# How to correctly receive a message from the queue IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

This code should read from the queue, if the queue is empty, then repeat reading through the timer check the format of Text or Byte. Is it correct in this format to check an empty queue? And will the timer work in this case?
It is not possible to check yet because the MQ queue is not configured.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
boolean tru = true;

        try {
            /*MQ Конфигурация подключения*/
            MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("SVRCONN");
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("MQ_APPLE");
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
            QueueConnection queueConnection = mqQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection("name", "pass");
            MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");
            MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);
            queueConnection.start();

          while(tru){
              TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) receiver.receive();
              if(receivedMessage != null){
                  MStart(receivedMessage);
                  tru = false;
              } else {
                  Timer timer = new Timer(10000,new ActionListener() {
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                          System.out.println("Timer Run");
                      }
                  });
                  timer.start();
              }
          }

            receiver.close();
            session.close();
            queueConnection.close();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void MStart(TextMessage receivedMessage) throws JMSException {
            if (receivedMessage instanceof BytesMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) receivedMessage;
                System.out.println("Received message '"
                        + textMessage.getText() + "'");
            } else if (receivedMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                System.out.println("Received message: " + receivedMessage.getText());
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your `receiver.receive();` call will block indefinitely. From `MQMessageConsumer` doc :

> Receives the next message produced for this message consumer.  This
>   call blocks indefinitely until a message is produced or until this
>   message consumer is closed.

if you want to read from the queue for a specified amount of time, maybe you should better use the `receive(long timeout)` method :

> public javax.jms.Message receive(long timeout)
>                             throws javax.jms.JMSException
>
> Receives the next message that arrives within the specified timeout
>   interval.  This call blocks until a message arrives, the timeout
>   expires, or this message consumer is closed. A timeout of zero never
>   expires, and the call blocks indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a need to use timer, I prefer using a `receive(timeout)`. If there was a message in the queue, the receive call will return with message else it will timeout with exception with 2033 reason code will be thrown. You can catch this exception and call receive again to wait for message. This will also allow you stop this thread when asked to.

Instead of `(TextMessage) receiver.receive()` just do `Message msg = receiver.receive()` and then use `if(msg instanceof TextMessage)` to determine type of message received.